# Converting an SVG to PNG and keep transparency does not work

Tags: php, svg, imagemagick, transparency

I am trying to convert an SVG to PNG and keep the transparency, but that does not work. Instead, I get a **black** background.

This is my code:

```
$png = new Imagick();
$png->setBackgroundColor(new ImagickPixel("transparent"));
$png->readImageBlob($svg);
$png->setImageFormat("png32");
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ok, I fixed it (finally) by upgrading to the newest version of ImageMagick (and IMagick) - weird that it didn't work before.

Comment: What specific version worked? I'm using 8:6.7.7.10-6ubuntu3 and saving a png imageblob with transparency turned black.